# Python app not running within virtualenv even though it is activated

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've a Python project for which I created a virtualenv called venv. I enabled it and tried to run my application I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sdk_config'
```

`pip list` confirmed that it was not installed so I installed it with:

```
pip install /path/to/sdk_config
```

Another `pip list` confirmed it had installed. When I then re-ran my application I got the same `ModuleNotFoundError`.

After some trial and error I closed out of my venv with `deactivate` anf ran `pip list`. Again I could see `sdk_config` was not installed so I installed it there, whent back into my virtualenv and was able to successfully run my application. I assume my virtualenv isn't working or isn't setup correctly. Is there any way I can check this and get working withing the virtualenv?

Comment: How are you running the Python program?

Comment: which os and python you have tried please put more and clear information

Comment: @tripleee I'm sure the problem is in the shebang line — it poinst to the system python so the virtual environment is not used at all.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too; but why isn't this information in the question, and what is your question then? Use a correct shebang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exited my terminal, opened a fresh one and everything worked as expected once I activated my venv.